# Vim function hints for C

Tags: vim, autocomplete, syntax-highlighting, code-completion, code-hinting

I'm trying to achieve something simple, usually called "function hints". For example, scintilla-based editors have it:

[image]

You type a name, and just get the prototype. There are a few problems with that in vim:

- You have to rebuild the ctags to keep it up to date
- You can't type C-X C-O *after* the `(`, you'll just get "Pattern not found"
- You can't type C-X C-O in normal mode, the cursor will just jump around
- You get the annoying preview window at the top

I've tried a few plugins; most of them mess things up even more [^1].Can anyone recommend a simple way to get just that ? A simple rectangle containing the function prototype and nothing more.

[^1] It's really mind-numbing how idiotic some of these plugins are. One plugin (I won't mention it) actually contained *in the .vim file* a list of functions from libc.

Comment: *One plugin (I won't mention it) actually contained in the .vim file a list of functions from libc*. What's wrong with that? You'll have a database somewhere, right? Or is the problem that the DB isn't stored in a secret unreadable proprietary format?

Comment: @eckes That plugin already uses ctags.

Comment: :-) ok. Then it's a bad idea.

Answer (score 8):

`ctags` for autocompletion is a mess. I suggest you try a compiler based plugin such as [clang-complete](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3302) or [gcc-sense](http://cx4a.org/software/gccsense/) (haven't tried this one). Advantages are:

- more accuracy as what they do is pretty much compiling
- compile errors are marked on the fly over the source code

> You have to rebuild the ctags to keep it up to date

you don't need to deal with ctags (they are still useful to jump around though)

> You can't type C-X C-O after the (, you'll just get "Pattern not found"

what would you expect?

> You can't type C-X C-O in normal mode, the cursor will just jump around

you can always remap that sequence if you think it's a frequent mistake (something like `nnoremap <C-x><C-o> a<C-x><C-o>`)

> You get the annoying preview window at the top

You can disable this by removing `preview` from`completeopt` option. see `:help completeopt`

I'm using the following setup:

[image: here]

- [clang-complete](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3302) for completion
- [supertab](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1643) to complete with `tab` key
- [ultisnips](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2715) for function signature placeholders. (also works with [snipmate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540))

and some vimrc settings:

```
set pumheight=10             " so the complete menu doesn't get too big
set completeopt=menu,longest " menu, menuone, longest and preview
let g:SuperTabDefaultCompletionType='context'
let g:clang_complete_auto=0  " I can start the autocompletion myself, thanks..
let g:clang_snippets=1       " use a snippet engine for placeholders
let g:clang_snippets_engine='ultisnips'
let g:clang_auto_select=2    " automatically select and insert the first match
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `eclim` (plugin for integration with Eclipse).

This solution is overheaded a lot but it works in all cases.